# Conditional probability simple problem

Tags: probability

Knowing that event $ A$ leads to event $B$, event $B$ and event $C$ are mutually exclusive and $P(A) = 0.3$, $P(B) = 0.8$ find $P(A|BC^C)$

I know that
$P(A|BC^C) = P(ABC^C)/P(BC^C)$. Because events $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive it means that $P(BC) = 0$. Hence $P(BC^C)=1$. However I don't know what to do with $P(ABC^C)$

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive implies that $P(BC^C)=P(B)$ and $P(ABC^C)=P(AB)$. On the other hand, since $A$ leads to $B$ we have that $P(B|A)=1$ and therefore $P(AB)/P(A)=1$ or $P(AB)=P(A)$. Finally,

$$ P(A|BC^C)=\frac{P(ABC^C)}{P(BC^C)}=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{0.3}{0.8}.$$